# Why do people use JQuery with Reactjs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, reactjs

So I go through the questions on stack overflow often and I have been noticing that so many people are using `jQuery` with `Reactjs`. I know that `JQuery` allows the client-side to interact with the user, alter the document content, communicate asynchronously etc. But my question here is that isn't `Reactjs` providing us the same advantages or more than that. And isn't using `JQuery` with `Reactjs` killing the very essence of `Reactjs`? Doesn't that affect the performance of the application?

Comment: Why do people use JQuery?

Comment: Depends on the use case. Some people are more comfortable with jQuery and haven't yet learned how to use React correctly so they fallback on jQuery. Other people use it for some of it's helpful utility methods (ajax, animations, etc.). It's not *wrong* to use jQuery with React but it's probably a bad idea to use jQuery to modify the DOM while using React.

Comment: Same problem with Angular. _So many_ people use both Angular and jQuery together. They generate the DOM with Angular, then manipulate it with jQuery. But why?? It's clumsy, counter-productive, overly complex and requires loading two libraries instead of one.

Comment: Why do people add style to DOM elements through javascript? It works. That's all they are targeting.

Comment: Well, some people use NodeJS and PHP _at the same time_ .........

Comment: Maybe you people haven't got my question. @GolezTrol It's not why people use JQuery? It's why they use it alongside `Reactjs`? @zombie Your statement is just like 'TRUMP: I nuke other countries because I can'. The thing is `Reactjs` plays with Virtual DOM whereas `JQuery` does it with the real DOM.

Comment: @MikeC I agree with you but still, my question stays in relevance to performance and optimization of the app.

Comment: Someone started with one library, then added another one for a new feature and didn't have time to rewrite the old stuff. Or someone went to Stack Overflow to ask about JavaScript and the reply they got was "Use jQuery". There could be tonnes of reason to do this, and my counter question "why do people use jQuery?" is there because I personally don't see much use for it at all in this time where IE7- fallbacks and workarounds aren't needed anymore. But you never know what motivates people, and this question will mainly collect opinions, and quite a broad range of different ones too.

Comment: @ArslanTariq So you're asking why do people use sub-optimal solutions? I can only assume it's because they're not aware of how to make it optimal or have time constraints. No one goes out of their way to make there code bad.

Comment: sometimes jQuery is required for handling third parties, which can't be handled by reactjs.